# Why do reads block other reads in MyISAM?

Tags: sql, mysql, locking, myisam, locked

I have one really long running read. It is a cronjob run once a day, but the whole DB gets locked down when it is running :

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+--------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id     | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State        | Info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+--------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 464971 | paul | localhost | paul | Sleep   | 2264 |              | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 
| 472177 | paul | localhost | paul | Sleep   |   96 |              | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 
| 479527 | paul | localhost | paul | Sleep   | 1765 |              | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 
| 479528 | paul | localhost | paul | Sleep   | 1765 |              | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 
| 479623 | paul | localhost | paul | Query   |   83 | Locked       | SELECT `metaward_alias`.`id`, `metaward_alias`.`modified`, `metaward_alias`.`created`, `metaward_alias`.`string_id`, `metaward_alias`.`shortname`, `metaward_alias`.`remote_image`, `metaward_alias`.`image`, `metaward_alias`.`user_id`, `metaward_alias`.`type_id`, `metaward_alias`.`md5` FROM `metaward_alias` WHERE `metaward_alias`.`string_id` = 'http://profiles.us.playstation.com/playstation/psn/profiles/Kool_Aid_Dude27'  ORDER BY `metaward_alias`.`modified` DESC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 
| 479624 | paul | localhost | paul | Sleep   |   82 |              | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 
| 480057 | paul | localhost | paul | Query   |   88 | Locked       | UPDATE `metaward_award` SET `modified` = '2009-09-16 02:12:37', `created` = '2009-09-08 12:06:44', `string_id` = 'isaw5t', `owner_id` = 1135, `name` = '50 online matches won', `description` = 'Aim to win 50 online matches. (ranked match)', `owner_points` = 50, `url` = 'http://live.xbox.com/en-US/profile/Achievements/ViewAchievementDetails.aspx?tid=%09%5d%3a%13%1f%5d%1fGt%06', `remote_image` = 'http://tiles.xbox.com/tiles/6G/dm/1oCLiGJhbC9CCxtyGy1TVkRBL2FjaC8wLzE2AAAAAOfn5-lJZ-Q=.jpg', `image` = 'award/isaw5t.png', `parent_award_id` = 115242, `slug` = '50-online-matches-won-1', `points` = 43.9 WHERE `metaward_award`.`id` = 116054                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 
| 480571 | paul | localhost | paul | Query   |   84 | Locked       | SELECT `metaward_alias`.`id`, `metaward_alias`.`modified`, `metaward_alias`.`created`, `metaward_alias`.`string_id`, `metaward_alias`.`shortname`, `metaward_alias`.`remote_image`, `metaward_alias`.`image`, `metaward_alias`.`user_id`, `metaward_alias`.`type_id`, `metaward_alias`.`md5` FROM `metaward_alias` WHERE `metaward_alias`.`string_id` = 'http://live.xbox.com/en-US/profile/profile.aspx?GamerTag=Hendricks'  ORDER BY `metaward_alias`.`modified` DESC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | 
| 480578 | paul | localhost | paul | Query   |   86 | Locked       | UPDATE `metaward_alias` SET `modified` = '2009-09-16 02:12:38', `created` = '2009-09-09 01:21:08', `string_id` = 'http://live.xbox.com/en-US/profile/profile.aspx?GamerTag=jobbie%20man', `shortname` = 'jobbie man', `remote_image` = 'http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/jobbie%20man/avatarpic-l.png', `image` = 'alias/2ec3d391a311be936d9603f99dcfa353.png', `user_id` = NULL, `type_id` = 1135, `md5` = '2ec3d391a311be936d9603f99dcfa353' WHERE `metaward_alias`.`id` = 705419                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 
| 480579 | paul | localhost | paul | Query   |   88 | Locked       | SELECT `metaward_award`.`id`, `metaward_award`.`modified`, `metaward_award`.`created`, `metaward_award`.`string_id`, `metaward_award`.`owner_id`, `metaward_award`.`name`, `metaward_award`.`description`, `metaward_award`.`owner_points`, `metaward_award`.`url`, `metaward_award`.`remote_image`, `metaward_award`.`image`, `metaward_award`.`parent_award_id`, `metaward_award`.`slug`, `metaward_award`.`points`, T3.`id`, T3.`modified`, T3.`created`, T3.`string_id`, T3.`owner_id`, T3.`name`, T3.`description`, T3.`owner_points`, T3.`url`, T3.`remote_image`, T3.`image`, T3.`parent_award_id`, T3.`slug`, T3.`points` FROM `metaward_award` LEFT OUTER JOIN `metaward_award` T3 ON (`metaward_award`.`parent_award_id` = T3.`id`) WHERE (`metaward_award`.`owner_id` = 1135  AND `metaward_award`.`owner_points` = 20  AND `metaward_award`.`name` = 'Marksman: Campaign'  AND `metaward_award`.`parent_award_id` = 27034  AND `metaward_award`.`description` = 'Kill 4 enemies with one clip of a sniper rifle.' ) ORDER BY `metaward_award`.`modified` DESC | 
| 480580 | paul | localhost | paul | Query   |   88 | Locked       | SELECT `metaward_award`.`id`, `metaward_award`.`modified`, `metaward_award`.`created`, `metaward_award`.`string_id`, `metaward_award`.`owner_id`, `metaward_award`.`name`, `metaward_award`.`description`, `metaward_award`.`owner_points`, `metaward_award`.`url`, `metaward_award`.`remote_image`, `metaward_award`.`image`, `metaward_award`.`parent_award_id`, `metaward_award`.`slug`, `metaward_award`.`points`, T3.`id`, T3.`modified`, T3.`created`, T3.`string_id`, T3.`owner_id`, T3.`name`, T3.`description`, T3.`owner_points`, T3.`url`, T3.`remote_image`, T3.`image`, T3.`parent_award_id`, T3.`slug`, T3.`points` FROM `metaward_award` LEFT OUTER JOIN `metaward_award` T3 ON (`metaward_award`.`parent_award_id` = T3.`id`) WHERE (`metaward_award`.`owner_id` = 1135  AND `metaward_award`.`owner_points` = 5  AND `metaward_award`.`name` = 'Headshot Honcho'  AND `metaward_award`.`parent_award_id` = 101442  AND `metaward_award`.`description` = 'Kill 10 enemies with headshots in a ranked free for all playlist or in campaign.' ) ORDER BY `metaward_award`.`modified` DESC | 
| 480581 | paul | localhost | paul | Query   |   86 | Locked       | SELECT `metaward_alias`.`id`, `metaward_alias`.`modified`, `metaward_alias`.`created`, `metaward_alias`.`string_id`, `metaward_alias`.`shortname`, `metaward_alias`.`remote_image`, `metaward_alias`.`image`, `metaward_alias`.`user_id`, `metaward_alias`.`type_id`, `metaward_alias`.`md5` FROM `metaward_alias` WHERE `metaward_alias`.`string_id` = 'http://www.wowarmory.com/character-sheet.xml?r=Aegwynn&cn=Fantazamor'  ORDER BY `metaward_alias`.`modified` DESC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | 
| 480626 | paul | localhost | paul | Query   |   88 | Sending data | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `metaward_alias` INNER JOIN `metaward_achiever` ON (`metaward_alias`.`id` = `metaward_achiever`.`alias_id`) INNER JOIN `metaward_award` ON (`metaward_achiever`.`award_id` = `metaward_award`.`id`) WHERE `metaward_award`.`owner_id` = 9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | 
| 480630 | paul | localhost | paul | Query   |   71 | Locked       | SELECT `metaward_alias`.`id`, `metaward_alias`.`modified`, `metaward_alias`.`created`, `metaward_alias`.`string_id`, `metaward_alias`.`shortname`, `metaward_alias`.`remote_image`, `metaward_alias`.`image`, `metaward_alias`.`user_id`, `metaward_alias`.`type_id`, `metaward_alias`.`md5`, T2.`id`, T2.`modified`, T2.`created`, T2.`string_id`, T2.`shortname`, T2.`remote_image`, T2.`image`, T2.`user_id`, T2.`type_id`, T2.`md5`, T3.`id`, T3.`modified`, T3.`created`, T3.`string_id`, T3.`shortname`, T3.`remote_image`, T3.`image`, T3.`user_id`, T3.`type_id`, T3.`md5`, T4.`id`, T4.`modified`, T4.`created`, T4.`string_id`, T4.`shortname`, T4.`remote_image`, T4.`image`, T4.`user_id`, T4.`type_id`, T4.`md5`, T5.`id`, T5.`modified`, T5.`created`, T5.`string_id`, T5.`shortname`, T5.`remote_image`, T5.`image`, T5.`user_id`, T5.`type_id`, T5.`md5`, T6.`id`, T6.`modified`, T6.`created`, T6.`string_id`, T6.`shortname`, T6.`remote_image`, T6.`image`, T6.`user_id`, T6.`type_id`, T6.`md5` FROM `metaward_alias` INNER JOIN `metaward_alias` T2 ON (`metaward_alias`.`type_id` = T2.`id`) INNER JOIN `metaward_alias` T3 ON (T2.`type_id` = T3.`id`) INNER JOIN `metaward_alias` T4 ON (T3.`type_id` = T4.`id`) INNER JOIN `metaward_alias` T5 ON (T4.`type_id` = T5.`id`) INNER JOIN `metaward_alias` T6 ON (T5.`type_id` = T6.`id`) WHERE `metaward_alias`.`string_id` = 'http://kongregate.com/accounts/SrGato'  ORDER BY `metaward_alias`.`modified` DESC | 
| 480632 | paul | localhost | paul | Query   |    0 | NULL         | show full processlist                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | 
+--------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can understand the updates being locked, but why are the SELECTs locked down too?

Comment: Table-level-locking is one of the many reasons not to use MyISAM.

Comment: I tried converting to InooDB and my site slowed down a ton. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428678/is-innodb-sorting-really-that-slow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the selects are locked because they are waiting for your UPDATE to finish, even though the update is not running yet

I guess the order of your queries was:

1. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...
2. UPDATE `metaward_award` ...
3. SELECT `metaward_alias`...
4. ...

query1 is executing.. it takes long time

query2 comes, want to get a write lock, but cant, because there is a read, so it waits and signal it's waiting to lock

query3 comes, want to read but cant, because query2 already signal a lock

now you will say.. MyISAM is concurrent reads, query3 should read while query1 is reading.. but if that was the case, and query3 took long time too, you could make a **"starvation"** on query2, meaning it will never get executed if query1 & query3 took a long time and go after each other, example:

assuming query1, query3 takes 5 secs to exec

```
second | action
1 | query1 starting
2 | query2 cant start, waiting
3 | query3 starting
4 | 
5 |
6 | qurey1 finished (query2 cant start because query3 is still reading)
7 | another call for query1 starting
8 | qurey3 finished (query2 cant start because the new query1 is still reading)
```

Comment: you can improve your performance here by running a slave and executing your long-running queries on there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the server option --low-priority-updates to give `SELECT` statements priority over table modifying operations (`INSERT`, `REPLACE`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE`)

You can also use the `LOW_PRIORITY` modifier after your statement (e.g. `UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY`)

***Edit***: there is more information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html

Comment: Can I make my big long SELECT run in a low priority?

Comment: LOW PRIORITY for SELECT doesn't make much sense. once a long SELECT starts, it's still going to take a long time. what would it take a back seat to?

Comment: The OP has a problem, as explained in the accepted answer, where the update that is waiting for the select to finish is blocking all the other selects from starting.

Setting the '--low-priority-updates' option in the my.cnf file would bump any update operations to the back of the queue and the selects waiting to happen would be allowed to start.