# MySQL InnoDB indexes slowing down sorts

Tags: mysql, performance, sorting, innodb, myisam

I am using MySQL 5.6 on FreeBSD and have just recently switched from using MyISAM tables to InnoDB to gain advances of foreign key constraints and transactions.

After the switch, I discovered that a query on a table with 100,000 rows that was previously taking .003 seconds, was now taking 3.6 seconds. The query looked like this:

```
SELECT *
    -> FROM USERS u 
    -> JOIN MIGHT_FLOCK mf ON (u.USER_ID = mf.USER_ID) 
    ->  WHERE u.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND u.ACCESS_ID >= 8  ORDER BY mf.STREAK DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

I noticed that if I removed the **ORDER BY** clause, the execution time dropped back down to .003 seconds, so the problem is obviously in the sorting.

I then discovered that if I added back the **ORDER BY** but removed indexes on the columns referred to in the query (**STATUS** and **ACCESS_ID**), the query execution time would take the normal .003 seconds.

Then I discovered that if I added back the indexes on the **STATUS** and **ACCESS_ID** columns, but used **IGNORE INDEX (STATUS,ACCESS_ID)**, the query would still execute in the normal .003 seconds.

Is there something about InnoDB and sorting results when referencing an indexed column in a WHERE clause that I don't understand?

Or am I doing something wrong?

**EXPLAIN** for the **slow query** returns the following results:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref                 | rows  | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | ref    | PRIMARY,STATUS,ACCESS_ID | STATUS  | 2       | const               | 53902 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mf    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY | 4       | PRO_MIGHT.u.USER_ID |     1 | NULL                                                                |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**EXPLAIN** for the **fast query** returns the following results:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mf    | index  | PRIMARY       | STREAK  | 2       | NULL                 |  100 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | PRO_MIGHT.mf.USER_ID |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+-------------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The execution plan has probably changed with the change to InnoDB. You can get more information using `describe select * from ...`. Post the results here and we can help you interpret them.

Comment: Are you sure you linked to the correct bug entry? That one was last updated in 2007, not 2012, and describes a problem that occurs with `GROUP BY`, not `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @dwurf You mean `EXPLAIN`, not `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: @Barmar they're the same thing in MySQL. But you're right, `EXPLAIN` is better since it's used by most DBMS.

Comment: @dwurf I never realized that!

Comment: @Dwurf, I couldn't figure out how to add that in a comment, (I am new here) so I edited the original post and included the EXPLAIN.

Comment: That's fine, the more detail you have in your question the better. Could you also include the explain plan for the fast case? (with `IGNORE INDEX (STATUS,ACCESS_ID)`)

Comment: @dwurf, I have updated with the EXPLAIN results from IGNORE INDEX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the slow case, MySQL is making an assumption that the index on `STATUS` will greatly limit the number of `users` it has to sort through. MySQL is wrong. Presumably most of your users are `ACTIVE`. MySQL is picking up 50k user rows, checking their `ACCESS_ID`, joining to `MIGHT_FLOCK`, sorting the results and taking the first 100 (out of 50k).

In the fast case, you have told MySQL it can't use either index on `USERS`. MySQL is using its next-best index, it is taking the first 100 rows from `MIGHT_FLOCK` using the `STREAK` index (which is already sorted), then joining to `USERS` and picking up the user rows, then checking that your users are `ACTIVE` and have an `ACCESS_ID` at or above 8. This is much faster because only 100 rows are read from disk (x2 for the two tables).

I would recommend:

- drop the index on `STATUS` unless you frequently need to retrieve `INACTIVE` users (not `ACTIVE` users). This index is not helping you.
- Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428678/is-innodb-sorting-really-that-slow?rq=1) to understand why your sorts are so slow. You can probably [tune InnoDB for better sort performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1429273/1349518) to prevent these kind of problems.
- If you have very few users with `ACCESS_ID` at or above 8 you should see a dramatic improvement already. If not you might have to use [STRAIGHT_JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) in your select clause.

Example below:

```
SELECT *
FROM MIGHT_FLOCK mf 
STRAIGHT_JOIN USERS u ON (u.USER_ID = mf.USER_ID) 
WHERE u.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND u.ACCESS_ID >= 8  ORDER BY mf.STREAK DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

`STRAIGHT_JOIN` forces MySQL to access the `MIGHT_FLOCK` table before the `USERS` table based on the order in which you specify those two tables in the query.

To answer the question "Why did the behaviour change" you should start by understanding the statistics that MySQL keeps on each index: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-index-statistics.html. If statistics are not up to date or if InnoDB is not providing sufficient information to MySQL, the query optimiser can (and does) make stupid decisions about how to join tables.

Comment: Thank you. This is very useful information and your recommendations are appreciated!

If you don't mind a bit more explanation, I'm curious why the second table was limited to 100 results. Is it because once the optimizer defaulted past the two indexes in the USERS table, it had to use an index the MIGHT_FLOCK table? And then since the ORDER BY was applied to that table, the LIMIT clause applied before joining to the USERS table?

If I correctly understood how it worked (or even if I'm incorrect), now I'm curious about how multiple ORDER BY clauses would correspond to LIMITs and JOINs.

Comment: I think your understanding is correct yes. Of course if any of the `USERS` did not match the where clause, more than 100 results would have to be picked up from the `MIGHT_FLOCK` table, and reading 100 results from `MIGHT_FLOCK` would not be sufficient. In the case of multiple `ORDER BY` columns the limit could not be applied unless the indexed column matched the first column(s) in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: If you sort on table a MySQL should always access that table first or an sort file is needed when more records are needed. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b34870/11 .. mixed asc and desc will also trigger an filesort but using temporary is bad because the sort could be done on disk if the memory is full and using filesort (quicksort algoritme) is an bad name it doenst not say it sorts on disk bad name chosen...

Comment: using filesort maybe uses disk  i read sql/filesort.cc (Source code of MySQL) just now  i saw an quick hint   "IO_CACHE tempfile, buffpek_pointers, *outfile";  so maybe it uses an disk file with some cases.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: the word 'file' in filesort has nothing to do with disk or file. Better wording would have been quicksort.

Comment: @spikey i know but   you are reading incorrect   MySQL will use an MyiSAM disk based temporary table ONLY if the memory is full and there are more reasons read about this here .. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

Comment: @spikey filesort (in explain as "using filesort") can use an disk based file to hold soms results there is an hint within the source (sql/filesort.c) code off mysql that it can happen in some cases..

Comment: @spikey also mentioned here https://blogs.oracle.com/realneel/entry/improving_filesort_performance_in_mysql "The reason it has the prefix "file" is because temporary files may be used to store intermediate results."